# ExpressJS/Request - Make a POST request after GET

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node.js, so bear with me here. I am trying to make a POST request after a GET. Idea is once user hits the homepage, I want to redirect that user to salesforce and do an OAUth dance. I am using expressJS and mikeal's request. This is the code I have so far

```
server.get('/', function(req, res){

var client_id = "xxx";
var client_secret = "xxx";
var redirect_uri = "https://192.168.233.105:8000/callback";
var grant_type = "authorization_code";


var remotereq = request.post('https://na1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token').form(

{"client_id":client_id,
"client_secret":client_secret,
"redirect_uri":redirect_uri,
"grant_type":grant_type,
"immediate":'true'
}

);


//How do I get the expressJS res object to use the remotereq object? 

});
```

When I hit the home page, the request just hangs. I am thinking I have to somehow get the expressJS response object to play nice with the mikeal/request object. How do I connect the two together?

Comment: If you want to save yourself some trouble, you could take a look at [node-salesforce](https://github.com/stomita/node-salesforce#authorization-request) or [passport-forcedotcom](https://github.com/joshbirk/passport-forcedotcom). Otherwise, I'm not entirely sure what your intentions are. You can pipe the results of `request.post` to the response using `remotereq.pipe(res)`, but I don't quite see the purpose of doing that.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the tip about the existing tools, I will check them out. What I basically want to do is, issue a POST request to the salesforce endpoint as soon as the user hits the homepage.

Comment: And send the result of that request to the client? If so, the pipe should be enough.

Comment: @robertklep . Yes. and your suggestion about the pipe worked! Handles redirects too...thanks robert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe the result of `request.post` directly to `res`:

```
remotereq.pipe(res);
```

That would send the result to the client verbatim, including all original headers.